# Where is the Apps Script located which Google Account is referring to?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive, google-account, privacy, security

### Scenario

Under **myaccount.google.com > security > Third party apps** page, there are a few App Scripts apps listed, like so:

[image: gif screencast of google accounts page third-party access showing scripts but no link to them]

But there is no link or project ID or any way to actually reach or identify these apps? (Please also see updates to this question further below.)

### Question:

How to get the URL of the the Apps Script script which Third Party apps page is displaying so that I can rename them (or deal with them about permissions, etc)?

(NOTE: I am <strike>pretty</strike> almost sure these are all my scripts and not a hack situation, etc. I have a lazy tendency to leave the new apps-script scripts' default name "script".  So all I need here is the ID or url to the scripts so that I can open them to reinspect permissions etc. This may qualify this as a security/privacy issue to if I didn't know better.)

Thank you.

## Addendum/Updates

1. Further to an answer below, I have also checked *script.google.com*'s tabs (Starred Projects, My Projects, All Projects, Shared with Me, Trash, My Executions, My Triggers etc), and where none of the scripts are named `script` any more. I still see a number of scripts named `script` on this Google Account Third Party page, and still no way of knowing where they are coming from.
2. I have now also checked Gmail add-ons and Google sheets and docs add-ons. There are none. The `script` scripts continue to be shown on the Google Accounts page. (Again, these scripts I have suspicion are mine — as I once had a tendency to name them just `script` as noted above, but I just don't see them anywhere, yet they are shown here.)
3. (I know I can remove/disable them on this *myaccount.google.com* page, but that's not the point. I want to know where these are coming from on this page (Disabling them will make them disappear without trace.) And I also want to make sure that they are not actually pointing to any currently triggering scripts that I have and which I don't just want to turn off by removing them from here, as there is no indication of any project ID or any identifier here which provides a hint.)
4. I think I now may have a suspicion of what may be going on here.

   - If there's an Apps Script script (e.g. named `ABC`) showing on *myaccount.google.com* as Third Party app, and if you rename it to `XYZ` through *script.google.com*, the script name change is not reflected on *myaccount.google.com* and it continues to show that script as `ABC`. (Though the original problem still remains, which is that without any ID you have no way of knowing which ones are reflected as renamed and which ones are not.)
   - I have yet to test this properly, and will report back and will probably answer my own question thereby.
5. Now at *console.cloud.google.com*. Further to pointer by @Rubén below, I see only 1 project titled `script` at *console.cloud.google.com* (which I can't figure out how to rename there). Please note that there are still more than 3 `script` being shown in *myaccount.google.com*. That means the rest are still coming from somewhere which is neither GCP nor *script.google.com*, right? Any more ideas where else to look in this google maize? :D

Comment: I'm not seeing the same user interface :) (I checked my Google Workspace account and my gmail.com account)

Comment: @Rubén Google Workspace? I checked script.google.com as per your answer below. Should I check Gmail? Where in Gmail can I find scripts listed? Thanks.

Comment: I was referring to the screenshot included in the question body.

Comment: OK. That's just the screen shot of the Google Accounts page myaccount.google.com > Security > Third Party apps... where it says these scripts (which I cannot locate) need attention because of permissions etc (as mentioned in my question.) I didn't realize the UI was different for other accounts though.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the Google Apps Script projects owned by an account or shared with it in https://script.google.com no matter if they are standalone or bounded scripts.

It's worthy to note that

- the data shown in the third-party items might not be Apps Script projects owned or shared with you i.e. they could be Google Workspace add-ons (i.e. Gmail add-ons, Google Sheets add-ons, etc.).
- if Apps Script project is using an standard Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project instead of the default GCP project then the name shown is take from the GCP OAuth consent screen settings, not from the Apps Script project title, so you need to go to the https://console.cloud.google.com and review all OAuth Consent Screens (there is one for each GCP project).

If you are not sure what are those third-party apps, it's very likely that the best thing to do is to remove them.

Comment: I have checked script.google.com > My Projects and all my scripts are there except the ones named `script` which are being shown in Google Accounts page. Is there anywhere else these `script` named scripts are coming from? Thank you.

Comment: I have now checked all the tabs available in script.google.com (Starred Projects, My Projects, All Projects, Shared with Me, Trash, My Executions, My Triggers) and I do not see scripts named `script`. Is there anywhere further I could check?. I have a number of scripts named `script` showing in Google Account Third Party page. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I have now also checked Gmail/Docs/Sheets addons too (and have updated my question to reflect that.) Any further places I can check? Thanks again.

Comment: I see only 1 project titled `script` at console.cloud.google.com (which I can't figure out how to rename there).

Please note that there are still more than 10 `script` being shown in myaccount.google.com. That means the rest are still coming from somewhere which is neither GCP nor script.google.com, right? Any more ideas where else to look?

Thanks again to help explore this google maize though! :D